# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 449 (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, woocommerce

I'm getting the following error on Variable Products only (Woocommerce):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 449
```

This is so weird. On every hit, the js, css and images files which returns that error change. I mean, it is not always the same list of files.

Also, all links are broken on this situation, all of them returning Error 449.

**What Error 449 means?** Is it a PHP code, server or Wordpress error? I've never seen 449 before.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable the `modsecurity` rules related to `xss attacks`. Don't know why it's restricting some request which comes from Woocommerce!